# CodeIgniter Uploading Large Files

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I have set up codeigniter to upload small files < 2MB  and that works fine. But I am having trouble uploading large files 20MB >

```
   function stage1()
    {
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '200M');
    ini_set('post_max_size', '200M');                               
    ini_set('max_input_time', 3000);                                
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);

    $config['upload_path'] = './temp/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'zip';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);                             
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))                       
    {
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());   
      $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);                     
    }
    else
    {
      $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());        
      //do stuff
    }
  }
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the above code. I overrode the php.ini to accept larger files and to take more time executing the script but it still returns the same error:

```
You did not select a file to upload.
```

Again, this works with small files but not large ones.

EDIT: Turns out my server provider has limited file uploads so there is no solution besides to FTP the file in.

Comment: I recommand you to improve your accpet rate

Answer (score 14):

**Below code use in your php file.**

```
ini_set( 'memory_limit', '200M' );
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '200M');  
ini_set('post_max_size', '200M');  
ini_set('max_input_time', 3600);  
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
```

**set below code in .htaccess file**

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 128M  
php_value post_max_size 128M  
php_value max_input_time 3600  
php_value max_execution_time 3600
```

**Edit my answer after you comment**

**Update answer**

Set config parameter in your stage1 function.

```
$config['max_size'] = '1000000';
$config['max_width']  = '1024000';
$config['max_height']  = '768000';
```

After then try it.

Comment: Tried this, didn't work. Had to create a separate php.ini in the root codeigniter directory (where the htcaccess is located) to add the php_value tags you suggested.

Comment: check you php.ini file i think it is not working properly. because above the code in my answer i have already use in my project. its perfectly working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your server accept the ini "upload_max_filesize" property to be modified wit hphp script. By default it can't according to the documentation http://php.net/manual/fr/ini.core.php .

> upload_max_filesize |  "2M" |  PHP_INI_PERDIR |    PHP_INI_ALL pour PHP <= 4.2.3.

PHP_INI_PERDIR means that it must be writen in your ini file directly. If you have no controle over php.ini, you will not be able to override this property.